# SyntaxError: expected expression, got end of script with XML request onClick

Tags: javascript, html

I've looked around and can't seem to find an answer to my problem.

I have a function which creates some HTML:

```
function parseCountryList(countryData) {
    ret = "";
    for (i = 0; i < countryData.data.length; i++) {
        ret += '<option onClick="getStates(' + countryData.data[i]['id'] + ')">' + countryData.data[i]['countryname'] + '</option>';
    }
     return ret;
 }
```

An example of what I get in the webpage:

```
<option onclick="getStates(1)">Afghanistan</option>
```

And this is the function it calls:

```
function getStates(countryID) {
    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.open("GET", 'http://localhost:3000/api/address/state:' +  String(countryID), false); // true for asynchronous
    xmlHttp.send(null);
    eval('test='+xmlHttp.responseText);
    console.log(test); 
}
```

And I'm getting a "SyntaxError: expected expression, got end of script" error

I've tried putting single quotes around the country ID in parseCountryList, but that hasn't helped.

Comment: it may be the eval that is causing the error? what is the output of `console.log(xmlHttp.responseText);`

Comment: It seems to print just a blank space, but the error is gone (from there at least). Thanks